# Query database onchange of dropdown menu, then output to form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm performing the following query on a database which is getting me a dropdown menu. I want this to query the database onchange so that I can use that information in another form.

```
$dropdown_sql="SELECT product_id, product_name, unit_price, unit_quantity, in_stock FROM products";
$dropdown_result=mysql_query($dropdown_sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($dropdown_result)) {
    $id=$row["product_id"];
    $product_name=$row["product_name"];
    $unit_price=$row["unit_price"];
    $unit_quantity=$row["unit_quantity"];
    $in_stock=$row["in_stock"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">$product_name - $unit_quantity";
}
?>
```

The dropdown menu:

```
<SELECT NAME=product_name onchange="dropdown_change()">
<OPTION VALUE=0>Select a food
    <?php echo $options ?>
    </SELECT>
```

I can detect the change in javascript

```
function dropdown_change()
{
  alert("hello")
}
```

BUT I can't get the information from that point, and the I can't put it in the form. Please help.

Comment: To communicate between your onchange javascript and the php code which queries database, you need either post the values on change, or use Ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

Add `this` in select dropdown.

change the select form with:

```
<select name="product_name" onchange="dropdown_change(this)">
...................
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdown_change(el){
        var elValue = el.value;
    }
</script>
```

Test: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7prR9/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery library,

```
function dropdown_change(){
    var val = $("select[name=product_name]").val();
    $.ajax({
        data : {key:val},
        url : 'your_url',
        success : function(msg){
            // do what ever you want
        }
    })
}
```